# Java code Synchronization issues

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have the following JAVA code that generates a request number based on the maximum request number received from database.

```
synchronized (this) {
    System.out.println("stsrt");
    certRequest.setRequestNbr(generateRequestNumber(certInsuranceRequestAddRq
                        .getAccountInfo().getAccountNumberId()));
    System.out.println("outside funcvtion"+certRequest.getRequestNbr());
    ItemIdInfo itemIdInfo = new ItemIdInfo();

    dao.insert(certRequest);
    System.out.println("end");
}
```

To understand the flow I have put `System.out.println()` statements in my code, the results of which are as follows:

```
stsrt
stsrt
inside function request number37
outside funcvtion37
inside function request number37
outside funcvtion37
end
end
```

The "inside function request" depicts my function call `generateRequestNumber()` which generates the Request number based on database.
If you notice the `System.out.println()` statements, when two threads run at the same time, both enter the Synchronized code together, (as I get the "stsrt" statements together at the beginning), also both the threads exit the code together(as I get the "end" statements together at the end).

**Question:** How could I synchronize my code so that first one thread completes execution and then another?

Comment: Are you using any framework? You can make this class singleton.

Comment: And also show how you are calling this code multiple times(shown in your output)?

Comment: Naman, making it singleton isn't possible for me

Comment: Change your first output to this: `System.out.println("start " + System.identityHashCode(this));` and post the results.

Comment: This is the result start 22061872
inside function request number40
outside funcvtion40
B2F11DF9-2988-4401-BF82-3817C24BEE96
end
start 27720104
inside function request number40
outside funcvtion40
2B2533A5-F775-41F1-BD31-FE8F4B81626E
end                                                                                                                            However I had used synchronized (this.getClass()) this time in place of synchronized (this)

Comment: @pkn1230, how you are calling this code? And also `generateRequestNumber()` method code.

Comment: I have my class, ABC.java,where I have the invokeService() method. from there i call addRequest(""); which contains my above Code. All this functionality is done in my back end, when i get a call from my Front end.

Comment: Ok. So you have multiple instance of ABC.java class and because of that `synchronized (this)` is not working as expected. You can check your front end code, in that you might be doing `new (ABC)`, which result in independent objects of ABC class.

Comment: You have solved it using @Javy 's answer. Now you have problem of generateRequestNumber.

Comment: exactly, Naman Gala, that's my issue now.

Comment: For that we need to look at the `generateRequestNumber` method. Personally I would prefer @codebender method.

Comment: Is one of the inside method  from                                   [certRequest.setRequestNbr(generateRequestNumber(certInsuranceRequestAddRq.getAccountInfo().getAccountNumberId())); ItemIdInfo itemIdInfo = new ItemIdInfo(); dao.insert(certRequest); ... ] calling the method containing synchronised block recursively, if so it might enter the block. Can you try hiding this call and see whats the output.

Comment: @amit , there are no recursive calls inside my code.

Comment: If a thread holds a lock of object the other threads can never hold that lock till first thread release it, but same thread may enter the method again. (Re entrent). Can you comment the 3 lines and tell the output.

Comment: these are the results: start 6079787
end
start 3528662
end

Comment: Hi, As per my analysis , the issue is the two threads are running individually, i..e one thread is not waiting for the other to finish its execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt, you may create `object` in every thread, the `this` represents different object, Hence it can access them in parallel. you can do as the following below

```
synchronized (this.getClass())
```

Comment: This helps me with my multithread call. following are my system.out.println() results. stsrt
inside function request number38
outside funcvtion38
D98F571C-F92E-4B3D-BB34-9260A5708FE5
end
stsrt
inside function request number38
outside funcvtion38
D1D34D96-1124-4B8E-9A22-A63E1A2B77BC
end.  However I still get the same request number. Is the problem because it takes time to save the details in database.?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you synchronize with.

When you do `synchronized (this) {}`, it synchronizes the block with `this` object. Which means 2 (or more) threads cannot access the block using the **same object** at the same time.

But in your example, it seems you are using **different objects** to access the method at the same time. Hence it can access them in parallel.

If you want to synchronize between all the objects, then use a `static final Object` in your class and synchronize with that object.

Like,

```
class Test {
    private static final Object obj = new Object();
    public void method() {
        ...
        synchronized(obj) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then it will synchronize between all the objects.